# Clarification to questions about friction and cars

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, friction

I'm trying to understand how car wheels work. In a perfect world the bottom of the wheel has no velocity. The wheels are in a state of pure rolling, which means there is no static or kinetic friction because the bottom contact point is not in motion. This would mean that in a world without air resistance a driver wouldn't have to push on the gas pedal, as there aren't any forces opposing the cars forward velocity. Is this right?

Answer (score 2):

> ... which means there is no static or kinetic friction because the bottom contact point is not in motion.

Motion is not necessary for static friction.

Set a book on a ramp.  If the ramp is not too steep, the book will remain in place because static friction is sufficient to hold it there.   Frictional forces in that case are not zero, but there is no relative motion.

Comment: So static friction opposes motion but doesn't require motion right?

Comment: Correct.  Unlike kinetic friction where you know approximately the force present from normal force and coefficient of friction, static friction you only know what the maximum may be.

Answer (score 1):

Your assessment is an idealisation. In reality, even if there were no air resistance, there would be other forces working to slow the car, namely friction in the wheel bearings, deformation of the tyres due to load, and gravity (if the car was on an upward slope). Also, friction plays an important role when cornering, and on cambered surfaces, leaving aside the central role it plays in braking and accelerating.

Answer (score 1):

It would vary in relation to gravity terrain environmental factors, to begin with an object in motion staying in motion, may be different for different environments, not typically considered such as a magnetic lake or typhoon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).